# Association of binned data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, standard-deviation

this is my first question here, hoping you all can help.

I have tenure and age data for an organization that has been binned already, and unfortunately don't have access to the actual ages/tenures of each employee. They're related, but not every new employee is young.

Both age and tenure are sorted into five levels, but the range of each level is different. So for instance the tenure levels 1 is <2 years and level 2 is 2-5 years. For age level 1 is <35, level 2 is 36-44, and so on.

How can I find the association between age and tenure for the organization?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Various approaches are possible. My first try would be to use 'levels' (bins) of each variable as categorical, find Spearman correlation, and test that for significance. If needed, perhaps see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient#Determining_significance) for orientation.

Comment: Thanks! The issue I'm having is that since each variable is in bins ranked 1-5, every data point is tied in rank with another, which seems like it undermines the meaning of Spearman's rho in this case.